# Finding the highest difference of pairs recursive in C / C++

Tags: c++, c, recursion

I am trying to write recursive code of the highest pair difference, for example: I have this code, but I don't want save my answer to array, and I need my recursive code only with two operators array and the size of array:

```
int theBigNum(int arr[], int i){
    int tmpSum,sum = 0;
    tmpSum = arr[i] - arr[i-1];
    if (tmpSum < 0)
        tmpSum = tmpSum * -1;
    if (tmpSum > arr[6])
        arr[6] = tmpSum;
    if (i < 2)
        return arr[6];
    return  theBigNum(arr, i - 1);
}


void main() {

    int arr[7] = { 4, 6, -2, 10, 3, 1, 2};
    int num  = theBigNum(arr, 6);

}
```

the return answer must be 12, because it is the highest close pair difference .
Help, me!
Thank You!

Comment: `theBigNum(arr, 6);` so thie size of the array is 6?

Comment: Your description of the problem is confusing. You mean difference, not sum, of adjacent pairs.

Comment: The language doesn't matter C or C++

Comment: My array dynamic, i gave example of the size

Comment: You risk downvotes by people who routinely downvote double-tags. See here for background: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361795/what-could-be-done-to-limit-the-c-and-c-are-different-languages-flames-on-qu?cb=1

Comment: Then the biggest sum is 13, not 12?

Comment: *"If you want to calculate the sum, don't use subtraction."* - Some wise guy

Comment: Sorry again, this is my array { 4, 6, -2, 10, 3, 1, 2}; and the answer must be 4-6, 6-(-2), -2-10, 10-3, 3-1, and 2-1 and to take the biggest number, and it will be 12

Comment: When you're using subtraction, you'll get the difference and not the sum. Fix your question.

Comment: @Lejik007, maybe 6-4, -2-6, 10-(-2), etc ?

Comment: @Андрей Москаленко  yes, it will be good too!

Comment: Compute the difference between two elements. Then recursively call the function to find the best difference with an array that's one element smaller. Then return the larger of those two results.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <cassert>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <class It>
auto max_op(It begin, It end)
{
    assert(begin != end);
    auto next = std::next(begin);
    assert(next != end);

    auto s = std::abs(*begin - *next);

    if (std::next(next) == end)
        return s;

    return std::max(s, max_op(next, end));
}


template <class Container>
auto max_op(const Container& c)
{
    assert(c.size() >= 2);

    return max_op(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}

int main()
{
    auto v = std::vector<int>{4, 6, -2, 10, 3, 1, 2};

    auto m = max_op(v);
    std::cout << m << std::endl; // 12
}
```

I answer this question because if you are genuinely interested in learning this will help you and if you just want to "gimme the code" for an assignment then my only regret is I won't see the look on your teacher when you present him this code.

Now let's turn this answer into a good answer:

For this to work recursively you need to pass a range as an argument and at each step to compute your *operation* (yeah, I didn't go with "sum", wonder why) between the first 2 elements of the range. Each recursive call shrink the range by 1. The link between the steps is of course `std::max` as you want the maximum of them.

To stop the recursion, you have two options: a stop condition at the entry of the function to check for too short of a range or a guard at the recursive step. While the first is more common, I avoided it because we need to return something from our function and it doesn't make sense to return something when we have an invalid range.

So there you go: a simple and correct C++ recursive solution.

Comment: :-) Somewhat mean and underhand, but appropriate.

Comment: @Lejik007 If you go an hand this in anywhere, be sure to be able to explain every single line in that answer, do not fall into the trap bolov dug for you to get caught in.

Comment: Maybe someone else, easy way please